# RewriteRule for subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, dns, subdomain, wildcard

I have a problem with my rewriterule in my .htaccess
To begin, i have a wlidcard on my website (*.site.com)

Here is the path of my website :

```
/home/www/static/
/home/www/home/
/home/www/.htaccess
```

So i made a .htaccess at the root of my website with :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} static.site.com [NC]
RewriteRule !^static/ static%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.site.com [NC]
RewriteRule !^home/ home%{REQUEST_URI}
```

These redirects run pretty good but when i want to go to for example :

```
http://www.site.com/img
```

There's a problem, it's redirecting me in `http://www.site.com/home/img/`

But when i type `http://www.site.com/img/` with the final backslash everything is ok.

Thanks for replies :)

Comment: Under which cicumstances do you want a redirect to `/home/...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,6}|/|#(.*))$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]
```

This should add on the missing slash for you if it's missing. You'd want to include the 'L' flag to tell the rewrite engine that this is your LAST rewrite and not to apply the other rule on top of this one.

Answer (score 1):

Don't match requests which map to existing directories

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

If that doesn't work, try matching whether the request plus another slash is a directory?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/ !-d
```

Comment: I put `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.site.com [NC]` 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/ !-d` 
`RewriteRule !^home/ home%{REQUEST_URI}` but it doesn't work :(